# Vastly different query run time in application

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, postgresql-performance

I'm having a scaling issue with an application that uses a PostgreSQL 9 backend.  I have one table who's size is about 40 million records and growing and the conditional queries against it have slowed down dramatically.

To help figure out what's going wrong, I've taken a development snapshot of the database and  dump the queries with the execution time into the log.

Now for the confusing part, and the gist of the question ....

The run times for my queries in the log are vastly different (an order of magnitude+) that what I get when I run the 'exact' same query in DbVisualizer to get the explain plan.

I say 'exact' but really the difference is, the application is using a **prepared statement** to which I bind values at runtime while the queries I run in DbVisualizer has those values in place already. The values themselves are exactly as I pulled them from the log.

Could the use of prepared statements make that big of a difference?

Comment: Hardware, configuration, statistics ? (just the usual suspects ...)

Comment: Hardware: Dell Precision 4600 laptop, i7, 16 GB ram, running gentoo.  Not sure what you want me to post for configuration since I've made many modifications to the postgres.conf file, largely to increase shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **YES**. Prepared statements cut both ways.

On the one hand, the query does not have to be re-planned for every execution, saving some overhead. This can make a difference or be hardly noticeable, depending on the complexity of the query.

On the other hand, with uneven data distribution, a one-size-fits-all query plan may be a bad choice. Called with particular values another query plan could be (much) better suited.

Running the query with parameter values in place can lead to a different query plan. More planning overhead, possibly a (much) better query plan.

Also consider ***unnamed prepared statements*** like [@peufeu provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120641/939860). Those re-plan the query considering parameters every time - and you still have safe parameter handling.

Similar considerations apply to queries inside PL/pgSQL functions, where queries can be treated as prepared statements internally - unless executed dynamically with `EXECUTE`. I quote the manual on [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> The important difference is that `EXECUTE` will re-plan the command on
>   each execution, generating a plan that is specific to the current
>   parameter values; whereas PL/pgSQL may otherwise create a generic plan
>   and cache it for re-use. In situations where the best plan depends
>   strongly on the parameter values, it can be helpful to use `EXECUTE` to
>   positively ensure that a generic plan is not selected.

Apart from that, [general guidelines for performance optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Erwin.  I think my next test is just to rewrite the query without making it prepared just to see what impact that has on the performance.  I figured there was the possibility of a performance hit with prepared_statements but didn't think I'd risk that big a hit.

Comment: @StAlphonzo: It very much depends on your data distribution. If a query can be much faster for certain input parameters you will lose with a general query plan. If input parameters don't make a difference, a pre-planned query will be generally faster.

Comment: thanks for the updates and the links.  In summary, I quickly converted 2 of my most costly queries from being prepare/bind/execute to having the values included in the query.  It turns out that in this specific case, prepared_statement is the bottleneck.  It's quite likely that our data distribution in this specific table is very clustered on the columns this query looks at.

Comment: Have you checked for differences in the granularity of the statistics?

Answer (score 3):

Erwin nails it, but let me add that the extended query protocol allows you to use more flavors of prepared statements. Besides avoiding re-parsing and re-planning, one big advantage of prepared statements is to send parameter values separately, which avoids escaping and parsing overhead, not to mention the opportunity for SQL injections and bugs if you don't use an API that handles parameters in a manner you can't forget to escape them.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/protocol-flow.html

> Query planning for named prepared-statement objects occurs when the
>   Parse message is processed. If a query will be repeatedly executed
>   with different parameters, it might be beneficial to send a single
>   Parse message containing a parameterized query, followed by multiple
>   Bind and Execute messages. This will avoid replanning the query on
>   each execution.
>
> The unnamed prepared statement is likewise planned during Parse
>   processing if the Parse message defines no parameters. But if there
>   are parameters, query planning occurs every time Bind parameters are
>   supplied. This allows the planner to make use of the actual values of
>   the parameters provided by each Bind message, rather than use generic
>   estimates.

So, if your DB interface supports it, you can use unnamed prepared statements. It's a bit of a middle ground between a query and a usual prepared statement.

If you use PHP with PDO, please note that PDO's prepared statement implementation is rather useless for postgres, since it uses named prepared statements, but re-prepares every time you call prepare(), no plan caching takes place. So you get the worst of both : many roundtrips and plan without parameters. I've seen it be 1000x slower than pg_query() and pg_query_params() on specific queries where the postgres optimizer really needs to know the parameters to produce the optimal plan. pg_query uses raw queries, pg_query_params uses unnamed prepared statements. Usually one is faster than the other, that depends on the size of parameter data.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will look into those.  You've addressed one of my concerns about undoing prepared statements, which is sql injection troubles and the regulations that I'm actually bound by as a result ... I'm still in a development/research phase so we have some luxury with time/trial/error I mostly want to understand the impact of these decisions now.   Thanks again!!

Comment: The #1 reason to use prepared statements is to amortize parsing/planning overhead when you will execute the same statement many times. However, in postgres, clever use of VALUES() allows multi-updates and many other ways to process multiple rows using a single query, with a great performance boost, too. These days in the PHP community, Prepared Statements are really fashionable, mostly for the wrong reasons (ie, to avoid SQL injections). Preparing a statement and not reusing it is slower, makes more roundtrips to the database, etc.

Comment: Personally I only use APIs which handle parameters automatically, so there is no way to inadvertently introduce a SQL injection. Python's DBAPI is an excellent example, and with psycopg2 it also handles type conversion (eg, postgres DATETIME <=> python datetime) for all types, including arrays. PHP has pg_query_params() which is nice, although it doesn't convert types. I don't know which language you use, though. In any case, if you don't reuse statements, use raw queries or the unnamed prepared statement, not named prepare + execute + deallocate (don't forget to deallocate !)